# JS/jQuery: When prepending a dynamic element, how to force the container div to extend upwards instead of downwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you've noticed, it seems that when `prepend()` is used, the additional elements get piled at the top but the container div is extended downwards.

Comparing with FB's load previous message, you will notice that elements are loaded on top of each other but your **view does not change**. It is like `append()` except the container div "seems" to extend upwards.

**I've tried doing this to *simulate the div extending upwards* but failed**

```
var scrolldif = $('#response')[0].scrollHeight-$('#response').scrollTop();
$('#response').scrollTop(scrolldif);
```

Here is the sample html to try. Just copy/paste/run in browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .chatbox div{
        height: 100%;
    }
    #response{
        height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function appendMessage()
    {
        var data = 'test';
        var message = document.createElement('p');
        message.innerHTML = data;
        $('#response').append(message);
    }

    function prependMessage()
    {
            var data = 'test'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            var message = document.createElement('p');
            message.innerHTML = data;
            console.log(message.innerHTML);
            $('#response').prepend(message);
    }

</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chatbox">
        <div class="col-sm-8 rightP">
            <div class="row contents">
                <a onclick="return appendMessage()" class="load btn btn-default">Append</a>
                <a onclick="return prependMessage()" class="load2 btn btn-default">Prepend</a>
                <div class="row msg">
                    <div id="response" class="msg form-group">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the answer but if there are better solutions, do share! It seems that my previous trial actually worked but the position of scrolldif was in reference to the top of container div so I reversed to reference it from bottom like so :

```
$('#response').scrollTop($('#response')[0].scrollHeight-scrolldif);
```

In my code above, just do this :

```
function prependMessage()
{
    //this scrollHeight is the total height of div including hidden parts of the
    //div caused by overflow BEFORE elements were prepended to it.
    var scrolldif = $('#response')[0].scrollHeight-$('#response').scrollTop();

    for(var $i = 0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
        //prepend elements....
    }

    //this scrollHeight is the total height of div including hidden parts of the 
    //div caused by overflow AFTER elements were prepended to it.
    $('#response').scrollTop($('#response')[0].scrollHeight-scrolldif);
}
```

Although the 'div' does not extends to the top, but it ***seems*** to extend just by adjusting the scrollTop value of the container div. If there are better solutions, do share!